# Will there be a Native API SDK for Here Maps for Windows 8.1 Store apps?

Tags: here-api

Now that Nokia Here Maps is released as a Windows 8.1 store app. Will there be a Native API SDK available for Windows 8.1 Store Apps also?

Answer (score 2):

Adding apps into the Store would not mean any promise of any additional API support. Also there is Maps API in Windows phone 8 which is based on HERE Maps data, but it has nothing to do with HERE Maps application, other than that HERE maps application is utilizing the same backend data.

As HERE Maps App is build by the team developing HERE services, and they are not bound with same rules on not having binary etc. breaks, they also can be using stuff not available in WP8 Maps API, as well as they also can combine other services & APIs in their app, just as any developer could.

All and all, if you are looking for any API for accessing Store functionality, then you should search for it, and not mix it with any Maps offerings, or non-native Maps applications.

Comment: So no plans for an SDK for Windows Store apps that has offline mapping capabilities?

Comment: Haven't seen any public roadmaps on Maps API functionality thus could not comment on it.